# How best to refactor this set of repeated trigger-calls across multiple methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Here is the code that I have:

```
var criterion = _.extends({},Base);

criterion.dispatcher.on('save',this.saveIt,this); //respond to event save. 

criterion.saveIt = function(){
 if(this.hasChanged())
   this.save({success:this.saveSuccess, error:this.saveError}); //method in Base 
 else
   dispatcher.trigger('done');
};

criterion.saveSuccess = function() {
 //do something
 dispatcher.trigger('done');
};

criterion.saveError = function() {
 //do something
 dispatcher.trigger('done');
};
```

There are quite a few functions that end with `dispatcher.trigger('done')` for ajax specific items. This is used to update a progress bar on the web app - it counts down after receiving `done` events from every element either on success or error or when it was already in new state. Since the counter is deterministic it counts up by the number of items and counts down by the number of `done`s received.

**Question:** Is there a better way to remove the repeated calls to `dispatcher.trigger('done')` at the end of each function? Or is it a necessary evil. We have such code in various objects just to synchronize the execution of the 'next step' so to speak (think of it as a 'synchronization barrier').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a method that appends the call automatically.

```
criterion.addProgressMethod = function( methodName, method ) {
   criterion[methodName] = function() {
      method();
      dispatcher.trigger('done');
   }
};

// usage

criterion.addProgressMethod( 'saveSuccess', function() {
   // do something here
} );
```

I'm not sure if this is any better than what you've got, but it's an idea.

Comment: Pretty much along these lines. I was hoping to somehow wrap the calls similar to AOP just to get rid of remember to put the triggers. I'm guessing in case of arguments it'd be `method.call(this, arguments)` correct?